# CMake custom builds directories

Tags: cmake

started to learn CMake custom configuration and got into a problem. How i can make a custom directory for exe build? Maybe it have solution in cmakeList.txt

i'm using "cmake --build . --config Release"
Like, in fact it building to Release folder, but i want it to be smth like bin/Release/my.exe.

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem.  Why do you need this specific output directory?

Comment: Just studying, so got this question

Answer (score 1):

You should configure in `bin` first

```
cmake -B bin -S .
cmake --build bin --config Release
```

or

```
mkdir bin && cd bin && cmake ..
cmake . --config Release
```